# Ruby/Tk Paned window 'orient' option will not work with horizontal value

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

Trying to add a Paned window in Ruby/Tk and I'm getting the following error:

```
C:/Users/user/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tk.rb:3016:in `_invoke': Attempt to change read-only option (RuntimeError)
```

whenever I add the orient option to my code like this:

```
p = Tk::Tile::Paned.new(parent) { orient 'horizontal' }
```

It seems that 'orient' is read-only (and defaults to 'vertical') for some reason? I noticed a ruby/tk tutorial on the web with a Paned window example and it avoided using the orient option, perhaps because they ran into the same error?

If you paste the following tutorial code into a .rb file and run it (no orient option) it works. Add the orient option similar to the above and it fails.

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

$resultsVar = TkVariable.new
root = TkRoot.new
root.title = "Window"

p = Tk::Tile::Paned.new(root)do
  height 110
  place('height' => 100, 'width' => 200, 'x' => 10, 'y' => 10)
  #orient 'horizontal' # <== uncomment this line to see error
end

f1 = TkFrame.new(p) {
  relief 'groove'
  borderwidth 3
  background "red"
  padx 30
  pady 30
  pack('side' => 'left', 'pady' => 100)
}
f2 = TkFrame.new (p){
  relief 'groove'
  borderwidth 3
  background "yellow"
  padx 30
  pady 30
  pack('side' => 'right', 'pady' => 100)
}

p.add f1 #, nil <== had to remove nil option here because this also caused an error
p.add f2 #, nil

Tk.mainloop
```

Has anyone else been able to get the 'orient' option to work?  I need it to be horizontal, not the default vertical value. I tried looking at tk.rb and following the error trace and it seems to indicate a 'method_missing' issue.

Comment: BTW, the tutorial I borrowed the code from is here: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_paned.htm)

Comment: Found a workaround, but it doesn't use a platform-styled Tile control. Substitute "TkPanedWindow" for "Tk::Tile::Paned" on the 8th line in the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the property 'orient' can be set but can't be changed. You can create a PanedWindow 'horizontal' if you pass the option at creation time. Like

`p = Tk::Tile::Paned.new(root, 'orient' => 'horizontal' )`

Forget the 'method_missing' call. Is a trick for dinamically creating the properties of the widgets.